# Indefinite article: “a” vs “an” preceding numbers with multiple pronunciations

Tags: numbers, indefinite-articles

Is either of the following usages correct or incorrect (in writing)?

> "An 1100 seat stadium"
> "A 1100 seat stadium"

1100 is commonly "read"/pronounced as both "eleven hundred" and "one thousand, one hundred" ("one" in the latter case has a consonant sound "w").

To me neither usage is an unreasonable. Thoughts?

Comment: As you suspect, it is all about the pronunciation. The problem your reader may encounter is they may see "a 1100" as "a eleven-hundred" and be brought up short while they process that "error". If you have room, it's never bad to spell it out.

Comment: You can always rewrite the sentence to avoid this problem.

Comment: @AndySchweig - Absolutely. And "A stadium with 1100 seats" also avoids the problem of "What's a 'seat stadium'?"

Answer (score 2):

As the writer, you choose how you want the reader to read it.  If you want the reader to say eleven hundred, write the words or 1100.  If you want the reader to say one thousand, one hundred, write the words or 1,100, with the comma.

Comment: This occurred to me after posting the question though a friend argued that 1,100 is still most commonly read as "eleven hundred". Would you consider "an 1,100 ..." poor usage?

Comment: And "1100" can easily be read as "one-thousand one-hundred". I agree that either pronunciation is possible, but the comma doesn't mean much.

Comment: I agree that the comma is defining. That there are people who cannot see the difference should not be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The use of *a* and *an* is usually determined by pronunciation of the phrase. Consequently, whether you use *a* or *an* indicates whether you are saying *eleven hundred* (an 1000-something something) or *one thousand one hundred*. (a 1000-something something).

For fun, I put both possibilities into [an ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%201100%2C%20a%201100&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) and found that there isn't a large difference in how often each one appears in Google's English (2019) book corpus:

[image]

Skimming some results to verify their relevance, I found instances like these:

> Figure 5 is an SEM photomicrograph of a typical contact area after **an 1100°C test**. ([Smothers, 2009](https://books.google.com/books?id=P9lPpmIHkbYC&pg=PA666&dq=%22an%201100%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiI2cfxmfuAAxWNlGoFHc-kCRoQ6AF6BAgGEAI))

> By juggling with components already in production, BMC engine designers have mated the 1275S cylinder block [from the Mini Cooper] with **an 1100 transmission**, which is unchanged except for a much higher-geared final drive. ([Taylor, 2015](https://books.google.com/books?id=TxZzCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT126&dq=%22an%201100%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiI2cfxmfuAAxWNlGoFHc-kCRoQ6AF6BAgNEAI))

> For the experiments, we used a 1,100-song database... ([Bembenik et al., 2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=u7G5BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&dq=%22a%201100%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUpbrDmvuAAxVYlGoFHWMpD3A4FBDoAXoECAYQAg))

> Suppose that you design the perfect circuit , and it calls for **a 1,100** 2 resistor in a critical spot . ([Ross and Lowe, 2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=wbv7AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&dq=%22a%201100%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUpbrDmvuAAxVYlGoFHWMpD3A4FBDoAXoECAQQAg))

So both forms are out there in the wild being used. Anecdotally, I would guess that **a 1,100** appears more often in scientific contexts, where precise usage of standardized numbers is more likely. But it would take more footwork to show that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **an 1100-seat stadium**.  (Note the hyphen, by the way.)

I'd do that because I'd assume the **eleven hundred** pronunciation.

I'd make that assumption because Google Ngram shows it to be the preferred version by a wide margin, something like ten to one.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eleven+hundred%2Cone+thousand+one+hundred&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celeven%20hundred%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20thousand%20one%20hundred%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Cool tool but doesn't seem to allow searching for phrases with commas in them (like the standard and presumably more common "one thousand, one hundred").

Comment: Also seems a tad strange to estimate how a number is pronounced by how it's spelled out in literature

Comment: @Spencer C I've never been pulled up for using 'a NP' for the abbreviated form of 'a noun phrase', etc.